# Qual o erro na frase "Manutenção em equipamentos pesado."?

Tags: número-gramatical

Eu me deparei com essa frase: **"Manutenção em equipamentos pesado."** Perguntei-me se esta coreto ou errado. Coloquei em alguns corretores ortográficos como [languagetool](https://languagetool.org/pt-BR) e  [flip.pt](https://www.flip.pt/FLiP-On-line/Corrector-ortografico-e-sintactico)
e não mostra como erro. Essa frase está correta?

Comment: Claro, deveria ser: equipamento**s** pesado**s**. Sem s seria fala bem informal.

Answer (score 3):

Não consigo ver uma maneira natural dessa frase estar correta pela gramática prescritiva/formal.

Se a manutenção é em equipamentos que não são leves, então a **concordância nominal de número** não é opcional e se teria "equipamentos pesados", com "s". Se existe algo como "manutenção pesada", então deve ser com "a", em concordância de gênero.

Possibilidades rebuscadas de não estar incorreto incluem algo como um "do tipo" implícito: "Manutenção em equipamentos [do tipo] pesado", mas um erro parece bem mais provável.